# Mootools - Fx.Tween vs Fx.Morph

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm fairly new to MooTools. I notice that the Morph effect is similar to the Tween effect.

Is the only difference that tween is for one attribute and morph is for multiple.

Can some one please tell me what the effects are best used for, i.e two scenarios where one effect is suited more than the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fx.Tween` would be more performant than `Fx.Morph` when animating only one property, ie:

```
el.tween('height', 100);
```

Versus

```
el.morph({
    height: 100
});
```

What you don't want to do, ever, is:

```
el.tween('height', 100);
el.tween('width', 100);
```

Instead of:

```
el.morph({
    height: 100,
    width: 1000
});
```

Comment: And actually, I'd suggest using `Fx.Tween` and `Fx.Morph` instead of the shorthand methods.

Comment: because of the footprint of storing the Fx instances into element storage vs not storing it at all? or? i thought there are no real differences to speak of - certainly not in implementation. the only advantage for a 1-off tween/morph is the lack of a persistent Fx object (via `Fx.Morph(el, options).start()`). if you need to reuse it, there is no advantage to be had, imo.